# Redundant assert in Integer.valueOf(int i) JDK7

Tags: integer, java, assert

`Integer.valueOf(int i)` method contains assesrt to check that IntegerCache more or equals 127.

```
public static Integer valueOf(int i) {
    assert IntegerCache.high >= 127;
    if (i >= IntegerCache.low && i <= IntegerCache.high)
        return IntegerCache.cache[i + (-IntegerCache.low)];
    return new Integer(i);
}
```

The cache implementation looks like this

```
static {
        // high value may be configured by property
        int h = 127;
        String integerCacheHighPropValue =
            sun.misc.VM.getSavedProperty("java.lang.Integer.IntegerCache.high");
        if (integerCacheHighPropValue != null) {
            int i = parseInt(integerCacheHighPropValue);
            i = Math.max(i, 127);
            // Maximum array size is Integer.MAX_VALUE
            h = Math.min(i, Integer.MAX_VALUE - (-low));
        }
        high = h;

        cache = new Integer[(high - low) + 1];
        int j = low;
        for(int k = 0; k < cache.length; k++)
            cache[k] = new Integer(j++);
    }
```

So you could increase cache size by passing property value. But implementation will not allows you to set cache size lower than 127 (or it does?). So why they place assertion in `Integer.valueOf()`. Do developers not trust own implementation?
I understand that if cache lower than 127 `Integer.valueOf(int i)` would return wrong value, but such just could not happen...

Is it necessary to have assert there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do developers not trust own implementation?

This is precisely the purpose of assertions: to catch programming bugs. One wouldn't catch any bugs by assuming there are none.

Answer (score 1):

Whe you compile the code with parameter `-enableassertions` or simply `-ea`. Then the assert will kick. By default JVM provided to you is not compiled with that parameter. So this assert is ignorred during runtime.